# Why doesn't this arithmetic operation work in GNU bash?

Tags: bash, macos

I have macOS Big Sur Version 11.3.1.
I can't do this arithmetic operation:

```
x=10
let "10 /= 3"
echo $x
x=10
let "10 %= 3"
echo $x
```

The result:

```
bashedit.txt:69: bad math expression: lvalue required
10
bashedit.txt:72: bad math expression: lvalue required
10
```

Comment: `let "10 /= 3"` means "set 10 to itself divided by 3", but you can't set 10 to anything -- it's not a variable, it's a constant. "lvalue" means something that can be set (i.e. a variable, array element, or something like that), and 10 isn't an lvalue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably meant:

```
x=10
let "x /= 3"   # replaced your '10' with 'x'
echo $x
x=10
let "x %= 3"   # replaced your '10' with 'x'
echo $x
```

With output:

```
3
1
```

(The left side of assignment needs a variable)